# Using uMatrix add-on in TBB and changing first entry node each time?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, guard

I just somehow worry about connecting TBB to the same entry node which may be hacked / surveillenced. 
Will it be more safe if I used uMatrix add-on in TBB to spoof my network identiies (I also spoof MAC address each time), and then change the first entry node each time?  Moreover, how do you suggest to change the first entry node? I just blocked the node IP by my firewall.

Comment: You're asking two separate questions. Half is answered [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/4099/71) & [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/4099/71), as Guard Nodes are meant to work that way. You could edit the question down to just the other, but the short answer is that additional add-ons are not only unnecessary, but tend to actually _decrease_ your anonymity.

Answer (score 0):

#### "Will it be more safe if I used uMatrix add-on in TBB to spoof my network identiies (I also spoof MAC address each time), and then change the first entry node each time?"

No. You will only be more vulnerable to tracking, and deanonymisation.

1. uMatrix "spoofing" identities will fail, see [this answer for more details.](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/11701/most-common-tor-browser-configuration-panopticlick/11705#11705)
2. Changing entry node all the time means that if there were a bad guard and exit pair trying to deanonymise users, you'd be far more likely to be deanonymised just by chance, and vulnerable to an attack where the exit forces you to be deanonymised by making you pick its evil guard. See [this blog post](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/improving-tors-anonymity-changing-guard-parameters).